# Why is $f'(y) \cdot (x-y) = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(h(x-y) + y) - f(y)}{h}$?

Tags: limits

Why is $$f'(y) \cdot (x-y) = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(h(x-y) + y) - f(y)}{h}?$$ I know that $$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(h + y) -f(y)}{h}$$ is $f'(y)$, but I don't understand how to get the equality I am looking for, without assuming anything about linearity of the function or anything.

Comment: Multiply top and bottom by $(x-y).$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we let $t=h(x-y)$, then as $h\to 0$, we also have $t \to 0$. Therefore, we can rewrite the limit as
\begin{align*}
\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(h(x-y) + y) - f(y)}{h} &= \lim_{h\to 0} (x-y)\frac{f(h(x-y) + y) - f(y)}{h(x-y)}\\
&= \lim_{t\to 0} (x-y)\frac{f(t + y) - f(y)}{t}\\
&= (x-y)f'(y)
\end{align*}

Comment: Shouldn't that be a $t$ in the denominator of the second to last line?

Comment: I tried to suggest that edit but it was too small. It was most-likely a typo on doeo's part.

Comment: You're right, I'll fix that.